# Sproutcore + PhoneGap/Titanium?

Tags: javascript, cordova, titanium, appcelerator, sproutcore

I'm learning Sproutcore at the moment to write my application on it.

The backend will only be a server that pushes json out to the frontend Sproutcore application.

I wonder how it will be when I use PhoneGap or Titanium to port my app to the mobile phones.

How much of the current Sproutcore application do I have to rewrite? Is it only the views and thus leaving the controllers and models untouched?

Cause Sproutcore offers a lot of UI and I guess I have to replace those if I want my app to look native (iPhone buttons, lists etc).

Any guides/tutorials on how it will look like when I combine Sproutcore with Phonegap or Titanium?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't expect to just be able to merge your Sproutcore projects and Titanium.  Titanium is 'javascript' but you aren't building a website on the iphone / ipad.

Only way you could do integration there is to fire up he Webview on the mobile device and have your Sproutcore files show up within that.

Comment: Are you sure is possible? Sproutcore files are generated dinamically with ruby!

Answer (score 1):

As Ryan said, Titanium is only a JavaScript framework without a DOM.

PhoneGap integration is more approachable. It expects to have a single index.html as an entry point and expects relative paths instead of absolute ones. Peter Wagenet wrote a [script](https://gist.github.com/609875) to do the necessary transformation.  See also [SproutCore mailing list thread](http://groups.google.com/group/sproutcore/browse_thread/thread/966741a0b3d52cb1)

If you don't need any native capabilities (Accelerometer, Contacts, etc), you could stick to a standard web app and not worry about Titanium or PhoneGap to transform it to a native mobile app.

Also, I expect we'll hear something from [Strobe](http://www.strobecorp.com/) in the near future about SproutCore (or a descendent) and mobile.